# Rails 3.2.12 controller action hiding from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have scaffold 'Category' which has table 'categories' and fields like category_name etc.
Now on my home page, I am showing all records.
If I click on 'show' of any particular category, my URL looks like this -> "http://www.abc.com/categories/1" where 1 is the id.
Here instead of "categories/1", I want the url to be in this format : "http://www.abc.com/#{category_name}".
I use friendly id but that makes my URL like this "http://www.abc.com/categories/#{category_name}".
I want to hide controller name and id from url and only display the category name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add something like

```
match '/:path' => 'categories#show', as: :category
```

in your route.  be warned that this should be placed at the bottom of your route so it takes least priority because it will match the index action of all your controllers.  Use it like

```
category_path(category_name)
```

Or

```
"/#{category_name}"
```

You may also need to remove the show mapping to the show action so it doesn't conflict with the named_route generated by adding the `as: :category` option

```
resources :categories, except: [:show]
```